# Android UI Thread stop other Threads

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a code in the UI Thread that call to another Thread. This new Thread wait for a server response to execute an database update.
When the new Thread send the post content the server send the answer fine, but the update process to the database stops when the screen (activity) load the next item to calculate and send it to the server again.
My code looks like this

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    onCreate(){ ... }
    public void pushButton(View v) {
        ...
        //Call the Thread
        MyOwnThread t = new MyOwnThread(arg1, arg2);
        t.start();

        showTheNextItemToProcess();
    }
}
```

MyOwnThread looks like this

```
public class MyOwnThread extends Thread {
    public MyOwnThread(String arg1, Object arg2) { ... }

    public void run() {
        if(arg1.equals("ok_status") {
            //The code on this part stops wen the UI Thread show the next item to process
            for( ... ) {
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried with send a clone of the variables inside the new Thread constructor, but the result it's the same. I don´t know why the UI Thread interrupts the another Thread. With the ListenableFuture (Google Guava) it´s the same.

```
ListeningExecutorService service = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1));
ListenableFuture<String> futureTask = service.submit(new Callable<String>(){
public String call() {
    //Send the post to the server
    }
});

Futures.addCallback(futureTask, new FutureCallback<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String arg0) {
        //when get the answer from the server, executes the db update
        //the UI thread stop this too
    }
});
```

I don't see errors in the LogCat. Your help is welcome, sorry for my bad english.
Thanks!

EDIT
I changed my code to use full threads (extends Thread), with WIFI connection the app sends the package to the server and the server returns the response, the app takes the value sended from the server and trigger the db update, it's fine!. But with the movil data (local operator), the app calls and runs the Thread but the thread simply not continue running. I had set the priority to MAX and it's the same. Anyone know why????

Thanks!

Comment: probably a matter of thread priority

Comment: what do you do inside showTheNextItemToProcess();? Have you consider using AsyncTask instead of Threads? for your case I think will be much better

Comment: I had use AsyncTask in situations that I need update the UI (progress for example), only inside Activities classes, but my problem is out of an Activity domain, it's a sub process called from an screen but the result of the thread doesn't matter for the UI. Need still use AsyncTask in this case? Thanks!

Comment: Hi guys! The Threads, FutureTask, AsyncTask are fine in every case, my problem was that exists an procedure in the app that calls `System.exit(0)` and alredy we know that happens with this. How can I delete the question? Thanks for all!!